# How to Implementation Dependency Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I would like to ask if how can I implement the dependency injection pattern with my current application layer.

My application layer is ENDPOINT, SERVICE and DAO. So the question is how can I implement the injector of the service to the endpoint and injector of dao to the service layer?

Please note that I don't want to use any framework for this, for example, the @Inject annotation.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to use a feature but do not want to use any implementations of that feature? That sounds a bit weird to me, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I just want it to be implemented from a constructor or setter perspective.. but the dillema was when I inject the service to the endpoint it will also include the injector for the dao..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
public class Endpoint {
    private Service service;
    public Endpoint() { }
    public void setService(Service service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void execute() {
          // ...
    }
    // ...
}

public class Service {
    private DAO dao;
    public Service() { }
    public void setDAO(DAO dao){
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    //.... 
}

public class DAO {
    public DAO() {}
    //...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create class instances
        Endpoint e = new Endpoint();
        Service s = new Service();
        DAO d = new DAO();
        // Inject dependencies
        e.setService(s);
        s.setDAO(d);
        // run
        e.execute();
    }
}
```